# Populate travel zone based on zip code

Tags: lookup

We have a location object with a zip code text field. We have a custom zip codes object containing around 40000 zip codes and their travel zone (A,B,C or D).

I want to populate the travel zone on location record based on zip code entered. How do I look up the entered zip text field to the zip codes object and get the travel zone and assign it to the zone custom field on location record?

Comment: Is there a restriction why you can't have the Zip Code as a lookup relationship on Location object? If you can have it this way, you simply create a formula field on Location to get the Zip Code's zone as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you can remodel your `Location` object to change the `Zip Code` field from text to a lookup, you would simply need to create a formula field on `Location` object to populate the `Travel Zone` from the associated `Zip Code`. I will recommend you to take this approach as it saves you from any other customization.

In all other cases, if you cannot remodel your object, then you will need to utilize some customization say a workflow field update, process builder or trigger on your Location object to populate the travel zone for the Zip Code on Location.

Comment: Hello Jayant, I was able to figure it out. I've built a process builder which would call a flow and update the zip code on location record from zip codes object.